# SES account credentials stolen email sending blocked

Tags: php, laravel, email, amazon-ses

Our SES account was compromised and some one used and sent about 50k emails in just 48 hours, our account has been suspended and another issue is we have added now mailgun emails details but each and every email coming from our ***xyz.com*** is going to spam. **How we can check sent emails ?** and **how we can no further avoid our emails to go to spam?**

Comment: 1. You need to figure it out how's your SES credential is compromised. And you need to submit a ticket to AWS, explain what's going on, and how would you prevent the same mistake.

2. use DKIM and SPF, avoid sending email with external link.

Comment: thanks @tirtakeniten sure I'll submit ticket!

Comment: Also You should tell all Your workers to create new passwords. According to the sent emails, probably without contact with AWS is impossible. (Unless You could check for instance some topics on SNS where delivery/bounced email notifications  were sent and then look it on CloudWatch Logs for any logs in application which listens to the SNS)